# Where is install location for the Kobo app executable so I can load a custom epub file?

Tags: epub, robohelp, kobo

For work, I'm trying to read an epub file I generated from RoboHelp 2017. I installed the kobo reader from the Windows app store to test it.

I need to know where the Kobo eBooks desktop app is installed so that I can associate the app with the epub format. But I can't figure it out. Typically, I just right-click on a short-cut in Windows 10 from the start menu and choose Open File location, but that isn't shown as an option for some reason.

I've searched online, and while I'm certain I'm not the the only one who has asked this question, I don't see any results on the installation location..

For example, Kobo's documentation website here...
https://help.kobo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020121953-Install-Kobo-Desktop-on-your-PC-or-Mac
... just gives instructions on how to install, but there's no installation location.

I also looked in my program files and x86 variety of the same, but didn't see any readily visible folders there.

Can someone give the pathway to the default installation location for this app from the Windows app store?

Answer (score 0):

While writing up my question and researching it, I found the answer to my questions.

The short answer is that by default, you cannot open Windows apps folders. They are protected folders and you have to jump through some hoops to make them available in File Explorer. This site gives instructions:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-metro-apps-folder-location

I ended up not following these instructions, as I found out how to load the epub file into kobo by using the Kobo app:

1. Launch the **Kobo eBooks** app.
2. Note on the app, at the bottom, there's a toolbar.
3. Click the icon that looks like a left-pointing arrow. This shows an **Open** dialog box.
   [image]
4. Use the **Open** dialog box to locate and open your .epub file.
5. After a few minutes, the e-book appears in the Kobo app, and you can access and read the book.